# ERROR: My Regression suite was working before, but after I carried out a gem update and updated Firefox to 13.0 Error is occuring

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

The error that I keep on receiving when running a regression uite, can someone please shed some light on this. It's driving me crazy.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in`open'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in`timeout'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in`connect'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in`start'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:76:in`
>   response_for'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in
>   `request'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in`
>   call'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in
>   `raw_execute'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in`
>   execute'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:189:in
>   `quit'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in`
>   quit'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:166:in
>   `quit'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:87:in`
>   close'

Comment: Do other browsers work? Can you increase the http timeout?

Comment: do you know what line in your code is causing that error?  it's hard to tell from what you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 13 requires `selenium-webdriver >= 2.23.0`. Update it and it'll work correctly.